# impossible to upgrade flutter on mac : "Unable to upgrade Flutter: no origin repository configured. Run 'git remote add origin "

Tags: flutter

I would try to upgrade flutter on my mac but I have this issue after `flutter upgrade`

```
Unable to upgrade Flutter: no origin repository configured. Run 'git remote add origin https://github.com/flutter/flutter' in /Users/quentinguichot/Developer/flutter
```

And tried `flutter channel stable`

```
git: From https://github.com/flutter/flutter
git:    0bffc8a391..0af027f805  flutter-1.20-candidate.3 -> origin/flutter-1.20-candidate.3
git: error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
git:    bin/internal/engine.version
git:    packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/android/android_sdk.dart
git:    packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/android/android_workflow.dart
git:    packages/flutter_tools/test/general.shard/android/android_sdk_test.dart
git:    packages/flutter_tools/test/general.shard/android/android_workflow_test.dart
git: Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
git: Aborting
Switching channels failed with error code 1.
```

I tried

```
flutter upgrade --force
   issue -> Unable to upgrade Flutter: no origin repository configured. Run 'git remote add origin
```

and tried

```
git reset --hard

issue ->. fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git 


flutter doctor -v


[✓] Flutter (Channel unknown, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Mac OS X 10.15.5 19F101, locale fr-FR)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.9 at /Users/quentinguichot/Developer/flutter
    • Framework revision f139b11009 (3 months ago), 2020-03-30 13:57:30 -0700
    • Engine revision af51afceb8
    • Dart version 2.7.2

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/quentinguichot/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /usr/bin/java
    ✗ Could not determine java version

 
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.5)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.5, Build version 11E608c
    • CocoaPods version 1.9.3

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions).
```

Previously I migrate to zsh it can change something ?

Answer (score 0):

If you did not make any changes in your flutter SDK try below command in the terminal,

```
flutter upgrade --force
```

this will forcefully upgrade your channel.

Comment: same issue
Unable to upgrade Flutter: no origin repository configured. Run 'git remote add origin

Answer (score 0):

The message states that you have some files modified in the flutter directory.
`git reset --hard` before changing the channel shall solve the problem.

Note: I'm taking for granted that you haven't done any changes to the flutter files intentionally.

Comment: I have : 
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git